# How to see if a class has implemented the interface with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm still new at `Roslyn`, so hopefully this isn't too stupid of a question.

What I'm looking for is a way to see **if a class has implemented all the methods of an interface** and if not, the highlight the interface, just like the built in "Implement interface" does.

So far I can see if the method name is implemented, but I haven't found a way to see if the right returntype is set on the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ITypeSymbol.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember` for this purpose.

Basically what you'd need is to go through all `IMethodSymbol`s of the interface and check if the type in question defines a method which equals the returned value of the above method.

Here's a draft:

```
var interfaceType = ...
var typeInQuestion = ...
foreach(var interfaceMember in interfaceType.GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>())
{
  var memberFound = false;
  foreach(var typeMember in typeInQuestion .GetMembers().OfType<IMethodSymbol>())
  {
    if (typeMember.Equals(typeInQuestion.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(interfaceMember)))
    {
      // this member is found
      memberFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!memberFound)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. just a quick follow up question if I may, is there an easy way to see which it doesn't implements?

Comment: Well yes: you should collect `interfaceMember`s in the `if (!memberFound){}`. So instead of the `return false` you'd have something like `notFound.Add(interfaceMember)`, and instead of the `return true;`, you'll need `return !notFound.Any()`. And before returning you can do whatever you want with the `notFound` set.