# Roslyn 2.x CodeFix that implements a missing interface, delegated to a member, VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**BACKGROUND**

I am seeking to create a Roslyn CodeFix that will respond to a Diagnostic warning from the built in Analyzer shipped with Visual Studio, that will identify the interface that is not - or is partially - implemented, allowing me to loop through the missing members, and generate custom code that delegates a method call to a Member field of a type that implements the interface.

(The Roslyn Analysers and CodeFixes that ship with Visual Studio do offer this functionality, but I need to customise and extend the generation of code, which is not possible as the Microsoft implementations are all marked as `internal`.)

**Please note:** The interface is almost always going to be located in an external, third-party assembly, to which I do not have access to the source.

e.g. starting from:

```
public class CustomDocumentDBClient : IDocumentClient
{
}
```

The desired outcome would be similar to the following (in practice I will be creating multiple versions that add additional code to wrap the method calls, once the basic principals are working):

```
public class CustomDocumentDBClient : IDocumentClient
{
    // Field to which calls are delegated, initialised by the constructor
    private readonly IDocumentClient _documentClientImplementation;

    // Constructor
    public CustomDocumentDBClient (IDocumentClient documentClientImplementation)
    {
        _documentClientImplementation = documentClientImplementation;
    }

    // Interface method that delegates to private field for invocation 
    public Task<ResourceResponse<Attachment>> CreateAttachmentAsync(string documentLink, object attachment, RequestOptions options = null)
    {
        return _documentClientImplementation.CreateAttachmentAsync(documentLink, attachment, options);
    }

    // Interface method that delegates to private field for invocation    
    public Task<ResourceResponse<Attachment>> CreateAttachmentAsync(string documentLink, Stream mediaStream, MediaOptions options = null, RequestOptions requestOptions = null)
    {
        return _documentClientImplementation.CreateAttachmentAsync(documentLink, mediaStream, options, requestOptions);
    }
    ...
    other methods
    ...
}
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have spent some time reading tutorials regarding the Syntax Tree and Semantic Model functionality of Roslyn.

I have also examined the Roslyn source code from GitHub - which *does* include the exact feature that I wish to implement; however, the code is heavily interwoven throughout various complex classes, and is implemented as `internal` methods, which cannot be overridden or extended, or indeed extracted into a standalone project.

From investigating multiple samples, and also a related SO question [How to see if a class has implemented the interface with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968887/1706008) I have concluded that I must use the Roslyn Semantic Model to obtain information about the interface, and it's declared members.

Once I can obtain the interface Members, I am able to build the required output code using the `SyntaxFactory`, and I have used the 'Roslyn Quoter' for guidance.

Creating a CodeFix from the default template, that responds to the correct Diagnostic codes is straightforward, and this is functioning.

**ISSUES**

The problem I am having, is taking the token identified by the Diagnostics Location, which appears to be a `SimpleBaseTypeSyntax` token, and

1. Verifying that it is actually representing an interface,
2. Obtaining a Symbol definition that allows me to enumerate the Members of the third-party interface.

The Syntax Visualizer indicates that the interface declaration node is of type `SimpleBaseType`.

I am therefore using the following code to obtain the token from the Syntax Tree as `SimpleBaseTypeSyntax`-

```
    // Find the interface Syntax Token detected by the diagnostic.
    var interfaceBaseTypeSyntax =
        root.FindToken(diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf()
            .OfType<SimpleBaseTypeSyntax>().First();
```

a) This does return a token that contains the information of the relevant node in the Syntax Tree - however, I cannot see any 'InterfaceTypeSyntax' type or IsInterface method to validate that it is actually an interface.

b) I believe I should be able to use `semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(interfaceBaseTypeSyntax)`, however this always returns null - bear in mind the interface is declared in an external assembly.

Is there something I need to do to make that information available through GetSymbolInfo, or is there another approach I should be taking...?

Many thanks for your advice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather embarrassing to have found this so quickly after posting, but the solution seems to be to refer to the `Identifier` which is a descendant of the `SimpleBaseTypeSyntax`.

```
var interfaceSymbolInfo =
semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(interfaceBaseTypeSyntax.DescendantNodes().First());
```

And, by calling:

```
var interfaceTypeInfo = 
semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(interfaceBaseTypeSyntax.DescendantNodes().First());
```

I can then use `interfaceTypeInfo.Type.IsInterface` to verify I have indeed found an interface type, and also access `interfaceTypeInfo.Type.GetMembers()`.

The answer was staring me in the face via the Syntax Visualizer.

[image: Syntax Visualizer]

**I'm leaving this open for now, in case others have a better solution... thanks!**

Comment: Nice one! Often asking it forces you to think about it in another way...

Comment: @JeremyThompson - yes, that was exactly what happened. I had to revisit all the steps I had taken, and then I looked at the Syntax Visualiser and saw there were child nodes, specifically the Identifier which of course is logical to be required for looking up Symbol or Type information...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the syntax node you are looking at refers to a type not a symbol. GetSymbolInfo will return null if the node you pass in is not a symbol. You want to use `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(interfaceBaseTypeSyntax)`.

Comment: Thanks, but actually it is that I was using interfaceBaseTypeSyntax, instead of the Identifier Token contained within it as a descendant.